# clisp: unable to search from a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I started learning LISP last night and I am currently writing a text-based Hotel Room Bookings system in common LISP. These are the lines where I have initialized my lists and vars :

```
(defparameter *rooms* (list 0))
(defvar counter 0)
(defvar room-num 0)
```

The following is the piece of code where I am manipulating these to search through my list :

```
(loop
(setq room-num(read))
    (if (and 
            (> counter 0)(equal t (find room-num '(*room*)))
        )
        (progn 
           (print "Room already exists:")
           (return 1)
        )
    )
(push room-num (cdr (last *rooms*)))
(setq counter (+ counter 1))
)
```

The above code is appending room-num to the room list if it does not already exist in the list.
The problem I have is with finding room-num in room list.

Following is what I have tried (Sorry if the code pretty sloppy. As I said I started working with LISP just yesterday) :

```
(if (and (> counter 0)(equal  (member room-num *room*)))
```

Also tried :

```
(if ((if (member room-num '(rooms)) t nil))
        (print "Room already exists")
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration is fine:

```
(defparameter *rooms* (list 0))
```

The following ones are not great:

```
(defvar counter 0)
(defvar room-num 0)
```

Special variables declared with `defvar` should be named with *earmuffs*, ie. a pair of asterisks, just like you did for the previous variable.
It is helpful when reading code to know that some variables are globals.

Also, you are writing a script that manipulates global state, instead of defining a function that only modifies a local state. For a small example this is ok, but a good exercise would be to encapsulate this script in a function.

```
(loop
(setq room-num(read))
    (if (and
            (> counter 0)(equal t (find room-num '(*room*)))
        )
        (progn
           (print "Room already exists:")
           (return 1)
        )
    )
(push room-num (cdr (last *rooms*)))
(setq counter (+ counter 1))
)
```

The formatting is unconventional, please follow [an idiomatic style](http://www.p-cos.net/lisp/guide.html).
Here is your code reformatted:

```
(loop
   (setq room-num (read))
   (when (and (> counter 0)
              (equal t (find room-num '(*room*))))
     (print "Room already exists:")
     (return 1))
   (push room-num (cdr (last *rooms*)))
   (setq counter (+ counter 1)))
```

I replaced `(if A (progn B C))` by `(when A B C)`, which is simpler to read.

Now, your problem is here:

```
 (equal t (find room-num '(*room*)))
```

You are trying to find `room-num` in **a list that literally contains the symbol `*room*`**, and not the value of the variable named `*room*`.
This is because you quoted the list: `'(*room*)` is the same as `(quote (*room*))`, which when evaluated just return the form as read by the Lisp reader, i.e. a list of one symbol.

You just need to call `(member room-num *room*)` to test membership, and you do not have to compare the return value of `(member ...)` with `t`, using `(equal t ...)`: if the test succeeds, it will be non-null, ie. true.

Also:

```
(push room-num (cdr (last *rooms*)))
```

You do not need to push the room as the last element, just put it in front with:

```
(push room *rooms*)
```

Order does not matter in your case anyway, and you avoid one traversal of the list for nothing with `last`.

Comment: Thank you soo much. You saved my life. I have been trying to get that search condition to work for a long long time. It was so easy yet I couldnt figure it out. Wouldnt have done it without your help.

Comment: Also thanks for the conventional formatting ways that you told me. Btw the rest of the code that I did not post here is dependent upon the rooms list. So I cannot push it to the front. I need to append them instead. Thats why I used last with push.

Comment: @VeryBhatti -- "_the rest of the code that I did not post here is dependent upon the rooms list_": you might reconsider whether you really need or want other functions to depend upon a specific ordering of the rooms list. That sounds fragile and bug-prone; you may be able to instead sort the list in the desired way at the time that such a thing is needed.

Answer (score 4):

also, in addition to @coredump 's answer, you could also use some existing common lisp facilities, like this (employing the `loop` macro):

```
(loop for counter from 0
      for room = (read)
      until (find room rooms)
      collect room into rooms
      finally (progn (format t "room ~a already exists in ~a~%" room rooms)
                     (return (values rooms counter))))
```

or this (employing `do`):

```
(let ((rooms))
  (do ((counter 0 (1+ counter))
       (room (read) (read)))
      ((find room rooms)
       (format t "room ~a already exists in ~a~%" room rooms)
       (values rooms counter))
    (push room rooms)))
```

although it is not an answer, approaching to a problem using high level facilities can save plenty of debugging time.